# When I delete the model, How can I delete the inlines data and the uploaded file

Tags: django, models, inlines

models.py

```
    class Issue(models.Model):
        issueId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        title = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
        year = models.IntegerField()
        issueDate = models.DateField()

    class Preview(models.Model):
        issueId = models.ForeignKey(Issue);
        previewPath = models.FileField(upload_to='./upload/magazine_sample')
```

admin.py

```
    class PreviewInline(object):
        model = Preview
        extra = 1
        style = 'accordion'
        max_num = 1

    class IssueAdmin(object):
        list_display = ('title',)
        inlines = [PreviewInline]

    admin.site.register(Issue, IssueAdmin)
```

How can I delete the preview and the uploaded file when I delete the Issue model? Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the Issue is not being deleted? The defaul behavior for the ForeignKey is to cascade the deletion:

> ForeignKey.on_delete
>   When an object referenced by a ForeignKey is deleted, Django by default emulates the behavior of the SQL constraint ON DELETE CASCADE
>   and also deletes the object containing the ForeignKey. This behavior
>   can be overridden by specifying the on_delete argument.

Are you using sqlite3? I'm not sure it has cascading enabled by default.

To delete the image, you might want to use the `pre_delete` signal:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from myapp.models import Preview

@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Preview)
def delete_image(sender, instance, using):
    # delete the image -> instance.previewPath
```

More info on signals:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_delete
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/

Comment: the issue and preview are all delete, and i want to delete the upload file

Comment: To delete the image, you might want to use the post_delete signal

Comment: i'm a newer in django's world. how to use post_delete signal?

Comment: Its simple, all you need to know is in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/ .
Think of signals as events; you register them and they get called later.

Comment: I have updated the answer, check the example. Note that I changed from post_delete to pre_delete.